# Python: SWIG vs ctypes

Tags: python, c++, swig, ctypes, ffi

In python, under what circumstances is SWIG a better choice than ctypes for calling entry points in shared libraries? Let's assume you don't already have the SWIG interface file(s). 
What are the performance metrics of the two?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't considering Pyrex/Cython?

Comment: ummm, yes -- the debate at work is over SWIG vs. ctypes! :)

Comment: Well, now you have new ammo and you can consider Pyrex/Cython as well. It's the middle ground between ctypes and SWIG: compile-time but python-like.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

SWIG generates (rather ugly) C or C++ code. It is straightforward to use for simple functions (things that can be translated directly) and reasonably easy to use for more complex functions (such as functions with output parameters that need an extra translation step to represent in Python.) For more powerful interfacing you often need to write bits of C as part of the interface file. For anything but simple use you will need to know about CPython and how it represents objects -- not hard, but something to keep in mind.

ctypes allows you to directly access C functions, structures and other data, and load arbitrary shared libraries. You do not need to write any C for this, but you do need to understand how C works. It is, you could argue, the flip side of SWIG: it doesn't generate code and it doesn't require a compiler at runtime, but for anything but simple use it does require that you understand how things like C datatypes, casting, memory management and alignment work. You also need to manually or automatically translate C structs, unions and arrays into the equivalent ctypes datastructure, including the right memory layout.

It is likely that in pure execution, SWIG is faster than ctypes -- because the management around the actual work is done in C at compiletime rather than in Python at runtime. However, unless you interface a lot of different C functions but each only a few times, it's unlikely the overhead will be really noticeable.

In development time, ctypes has a much lower startup cost: you don't have to learn about interface files, you don't have to generate .c files and compile them, you don't have to check out and silence warnings. You can just jump in and start using a single C function with minimal effort, then expand it to more. And you get to test and try things out directly in the Python interpreter. Wrapping lots of code is somewhat tedious, although there are attempts to make that simpler (like ctypes-configure.)

SWIG, on the other hand, can be used to generate wrappers for multiple languages (barring language-specific details that need filling in, like the custom C code I mentioned above.) When wrapping lots and lots of code that SWIG can handle with little help, the code generation can also be a lot simpler to set up than the ctypes equivalents.

Comment: Was struggling with SWIG and came across this answer.  It convinced me to switch to CTypes. [Why didn't I think to look on stackoverflow first ;-)]

A good overview of may be found at: http://www.slideshare.net/gnunify/c-types-extending-python

Comment: I much prefer CTypes because it avoids compilation altogether. This is particularly advantageous when writing a module that might be used on multiple platforms, and particularly those that don't have easy access to a compiler (such as 64-bit Windows). CTypes is also python-version-agnostic. That is, you can write a ctypes interface, and it can work under Python 2.4, 2.6, and 3.1 without modification.

Comment: I completely disagree and I am huge fan of SWIG. Once you get to know how typemaps are created, e.g. using the typemaps provided by NumPy, you do not need to worry about segmentation fault due to interfaces changing, memory alignment issues, index errors, garbage collection etc.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation why the C++ generated by swig is "rather ugly"?

Answer (score 101):

I have a rich experience of using swig. SWIG claims that it is a rapid solution for wrapping things. But in real life...

---

## Cons:

SWIG is developed to be general, for everyone and for 20+ languages. Generally, it leads to drawbacks:
- needs configuration (SWIG .i templates), sometimes it is tricky,
- lack of treatment of some special cases (see python properties further),
- lack of performance for some languages.

*Python cons:*

1) **Code style inconsistency**. C++ and python have very different code styles (that is obvious, certainly), the possibilities of a swig of making target code more Pythonish is very limited. As an example,  it is butt-heart to create properties from getters and setters. See [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183716/python-properties-swig)

2) **Lack of broad community**. SWIG has some good documentation. But if one caught something that is not in the documentation, there is no information at all. No blogs nor googling helps. So one has to heavily dig SWIG generated code in such cases... That is terrible, I could say...

## Pros:

- In simple cases, it is really rapid, easy and straight forward
- If you produced swig interface files once, you can wrap this C++ code to ANY of other 20+ languages (!!!).
- One big concern about SWIG is a performance. Since version 2.04 SWIG includes '-builtin' flag which makes SWIG even faster than other automated ways of wrapping. At least [some benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456884/extending-python-to-swig-not-to-swig-or-cython) shows this.

---

## When to USE SWIG?

So I concluded for myself two cases when the swig is good to use:

2) If one needs to wrap C++ code **for several languages**. Or if potentially there could be a time when one needs to distribute the code for several languages. Using SWIG is reliable in this case.

1) If one needs to **rapidly** wrap **just several** functions from some C++ library for end use.

---

## Live experience

**Update** :
It is a year and a half passed as we did a conversion of our library by using SWIG.

First, we made a python version. There were several moments when we experienced troubles with SWIG - it is true. But right now we expanded our library to Java and .NET. So we have 3 languages with 1 SWIG. And I could say that **SWIG rocks** in terms of saving a LOT of time.

**Update 2**:
It is two years as we use SWIG for this library. SWIG is integrated into our build system. Recently we had major API change of C++ library. SWIG worked perfectly. The only thing we needed to do is to add several %rename to .i files so our `CppCamelStyleFunctions()` now `looks_more_pythonish` in python. First I was concerned about some problems that could arise, but nothing went wrong. It was amazing. Just several edits and everything distributed in 3 languages. Now I am confident that it was a good solution to use SWIG in our case.

**Update 3**:
It is 3+ years we use SWIG for our library. **Major change**: python part was totally rewritten in pure python. The reason is that Python is used for the majority of applications of our library now. Even if the pure python version works slower than C++ wrapping, it is more convenient for users to work with pure python, not struggling with native libraries.

SWIG is still used for .NET and Java versions.

The Main question here "Would we use SWIG for python if we started the project from the beginning?". We would! SWIG allowed us to rapidly distribute our product to many languages. It worked for a period of time which gave us the opportunity for better understanding our users requirements.

Comment: Especially thanks for the Update part with real project experience after a year and half!

Comment: may be considerable to call 'lack of documentation' headline 'lack of broad community' instead if there is actually a good documentation but 'no googling helps'

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree, SWIG rocks. I even started to improve on SWIG with a different backend. The places I found the most useful with respect to examples were NumPy and of course XBMC.

Answer (score 14):

CTypes is very cool and much easier than SWIG, but it has the drawback that poorly or malevolently-written python code can actually crash the python process.  You should also consider [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/) python.  IMHO it's actually easier than swig while giving you more control over the final python interface.  If you are using C++ anyway, you also don't add any other languages to your mix.

Comment: Oooooh! Shiny new thing I didn't know about -- thanks for the pointer to Boost.Python!!

Answer (score 11):

In my experience, ctypes does have a big disadvantage: when something goes wrong (and it invariably will for any complex interfaces), it's a hell to debug.

The problem is that a big part of your stack is obscured by ctypes/ffi magic and there is no easy way to determine how did you get to a particular point and why parameter values are what they are..

Comment: I agree, things blow up if you mess up your arguments or indices. There is no type safety

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/), which can act as glue between high-level Python code and low-level C code. [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) is written in Pyrex, for instance.

Comment: "Cython is a language that makes writing C extensions for the Python language as easy as Python itself. Cython is based on the well-known Pyrex, but supports more cutting edge functionality and optimizations."

Answer (score 7):

ctypes is great, but does not handle C++ classes.  I've also found ctypes is about 10% slower than a direct C binding, but that will highly depend on what you are calling.

If you are going to go with ctypes, definitely check out the Pyglet and Pyopengl projects, that have massive examples of ctype bindings.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to be contrarian and suggest that, if you can, you should write your extension library using the [standard Python API](http://docs.python.org/api/).  It's really well-integrated from both a C and Python perspective... if you have any experience with the Perl API, you will find it a *very* pleasant surprise.

Ctypes is nice too, but as others have said, it doesn't do C++.

How big is the library you're trying to wrap?  How quickly does the codebase change?  Any other maintenance issues?  These will all probably affect the choice of the best way to write the Python bindings.

Comment: @Dan, the libraries I'm dealing with are third-party -- VMware's VIX API, for example. I have no choice but to use them as best I can. I use the standard Python API whenever possible, believe me! :)

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add a few more considerations that I didn't see mentioned yet.
[EDIT: Ooops, didn't see Mike Steder's answer]

If you want to try using a non Cpython implementation (like PyPy, IronPython or Jython), then ctypes is about the only way to go.  PyPy doesn't allow writing C-extensions, so that rules out pyrex/cython and Boost.python.  For the same reason, ctypes is the only mechanism that will work for IronPython and (eventually, once they get it all working) jython.

As someone else mentioned, no compilation is required.  This means that if a new version of the .dll or .so comes out, you can just drop it in, and load that new version.  As long as the none of the interfaces changed, it's a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Something to keep in mind is that SWIG targets only the CPython implementation.  Since ctypes  is also supported by the PyPy and IronPython implementations it may be worth writing your modules with ctypes for compatibility with the wider Python ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found SWIG to be be a little bloated in its approach (in general, not just Python) and difficult to implement without having to cross the sore point of writing Python code with an explicit mindset to be SWIG friendly, rather than writing clean well-written Python code.  It is, IMHO, a much more straightforward process to write C bindings to C++ (if using C++) and then use ctypes to interface to any C layer.

If the library you are interfacing to has a C interface as part of the library, another advantage of ctypes is that you don't have to compile a separate python-binding library to access third-party libraries.  This is particularly nice in formulating a pure-python solution that avoids cross-platform compilation issues (for those third-party libs offered on disparate platforms).  Having to embed compiled code into a package you wish to deploy on something like PyPi in a cross-platform friendly way is a pain;  one of my most irritating points about Python packages using SWIG or underlying explicit C code is their general inavailability cross-platform.  So consider this if you are working with cross-platform available third party libraries and developing a python solution around them.

As a real-world example, consider PyGTK.  This (I believe) uses SWIG to generate C code to interface to the GTK C calls.  I used this for the briefest time only to find it a real pain to set up and use, with quirky odd errors if you didn't do things in the correct order on setup and just in general.  It was such a frustrating experience, and when I looked at the interace definitions provided by GTK on the web I realized what a simple excercise it would be to write a translator of those interface to python ctypes interface.  A project called PyGGI was born, and in ONE day I was able to rewrite PyGTK to be a much more functiona and useful product that matches cleanly to the GTK C-object-oriented interfaces.  And it required no compilation of C-code making it cross-platform friendly.  (I was actually after interfacing to webkitgtk, which isn't so cross-platform).  I can also easily deploy PyGGI to  any platform supporting GTK.

Comment: You just need some patience. E.g. SWIG does not recurse headers, which mean that you interfaces must be well written. I have about 15 libraries now written using SWIG and a common type library. When it comes to refactoring and maintaining previous interfaces until deprecation, it is extremely flexible. My advice is find some examples using NumPy.i