# How can I mix C/C++ with python?

Tags: c++, python, c, opengl

I want to use C++ for opengl and python for scripting various social api calls. IS there a better option?

Comment: there are numerous alternatives: like lua, perl or javascript. if you want to take python: boost is your friend. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/index.html

Comment: There is previous answer about mixing c/c++ with python  look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153577/integrate-python-and-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype with your OpenGL calls in python - it is much quicker to prototype than C/C++ and then see if it is quick enough - if it is then you are done - if not then find the bottlenecks and consult the documentation on C/C++ plug in to address those issues.

Note that there are python OpenGL bindings available [here](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) which already use C/C++ on the OpenGL side so should be as fast as anything you are likely to come up with quickly.