# Implement Python Scripting Into C++

Tags: python, c++

I'm creating an application in Python with dynamic scripting that allows users to create their own Python scripts and manipulate the application. I would much rather make the application in c++ but I also want the custom Python script manipulation. So... basically I need c++ to read and execute Python scripts. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate Python And C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153577/integrate-python-and-c)

Comment: I looked at that. Didn't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to look at [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html). Here's the example from ["Very High Level Embedding"](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding) from the python docs.

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```