# Use python library in C++ for OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I want to access a library `MATPLOTLIB` in Python to plot scatter plots with ease but I am coding in OpenCV with C++.

Ultimately,I want to convert this to a mex file and invoke it inside MATLAB.

Can Python codes be converted to mex files in MATLAB?  Also, can the Python library be accessed in C++?

Any other alternative solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153577/integrate-python-and-c

Comment: Have you considered just writing the scatter plot data to a file using C++ and then just post processing it in Matlab or Python?