# Building a python interface for a *.so

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cython, ctypes

I want to make use of a `C` library, from which a shared object and the header files are available.

As the documentation of `ctypes` and `Cython` are very scarce and tutorials about those were for different usage, I need some help.

So, I don't know where to start here and which tool would be the easiest solution for a Python beginner like me.

Comment: Check out this question-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153577/integrate-python-and-c

Comment: this answer helps a bit, but the answer provided is 7 years old, so maybe it is a bit outdated

Comment: How large is the library? `ctypes` is reasonably easy to use and is builtin, but it can get a little repetitive if you have to wrap many functions.

Comment: The library is pretty large. But I finally managed to import and access it with ctypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to import the library with `ctypes`. `Cython` didn't work out for me, and seemed to complex with the different files needed.

After getting an error like: `undefined symbol: inflate`, the accessing really worked out with importing the needed pcap lib from the system libs. I just didn't knew that it was needed. I found where it is with: `find /usr/lib/ -name libpcap*`

```
from ctypes import cdll

def main():
    libpcap = cdll.LoadLibrary('path/to/libpcap.so')
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('path/to/lib.so')
    lib.function_from_lib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I hope, if anyone has this problem and comes from google, here is a solution which might help.