# How to I transfer an image(opencv Matrix/numpy array) from c++ publisher to python sender via ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, c++, zeromq, pyzmq

I know how to send a string message from c++ to python via zeromq.

Here's the code for sending a string message I know :

C++ sender code :

```
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
int bind = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://localhost:5563");
std::string message = "Hello from sender";
const char *message_char = message.c_str();
zmq_send(publisher, message_char, strlen(message_char), ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
```

Python receiver code :

```
context = zmq.Context()
receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
receiver.connect("tcp://*:5563")
receiver.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
message = receiver.recv_string()
```

What I want is to send an image from c++ zeromq publisher to python receiver.

Comment: Maybe use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` rather than `std::string`?

Comment: How do you have the image stored in c++?

Comment: @eyllanesc I've used the library opencv for handling images. Its reads image in form of Matrix object.

Comment: @Rohit You should write those things at the beginning of your question since c++ does not offer by default the handling of images so you will always need to use an external library. :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for pointing out. I've declared use of opencv library in the question itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Disclaimer :* 
*Answering my own question, so that others shall not stuck where I did.*

So lets get started.

**What is Zero MQ ?**

ZeroMQ is a high-performance asynchronous messaging library, aimed at use in distributed or concurrent applications. It provides a message queue, but unlike message-oriented middleware, a ZeroMQ system can run without a dedicated message broker.

Before, we get started here are the basics :

Protocol/Library used : ZeroMQ

Publisher : C++ oriented

Subsciber : Python oriented

---

**Sending String/char array message via ZeroMQ :**

***C++ Publisher :-***

```
// Setting up ZMQ context & socket variables
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB); 
int bind = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://*:9000");
std::string message = "Hello from sender";
const char *message_char = message.c_str(); // Converting c++ string to char array
// Sending char array via ZMQ
zmq_send(publisher, message_char, strlen(message_char), ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
```

***Python Subscriber :-***

```
// Setting up ZMQ context & socket variables
context = zmq.Context()
receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
receiver.connect("tcp://localhost:9000")
// Subscribing to start receiving messages
receiver.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
message = receiver.recv_string()
```

---

**Sending Image/ndarray array message via ZeroMQ :**

For handling images, opencv is an awesome library. Simple, easy to code & lightning fast.

***C++ Publisher :-***

```
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
int bind = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://*:9000");

// Reading the image through opencv package
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/sample.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
int height = image.rows;
int width = image.cols;
zmq_send(publisher, image.data, (height*width*sizeof(UINT8)), ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
```

*In above code, image is read as a grayscale image, you can read 3-channel (RGB) image as well, by passing appropriate parameters in opencv's imread method.*

*Also remember to modify the size (3rd parameter in zmq_send function call) accordingly.*

***Python Subscriber :-***

```
context = zmq.Context()
receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
receiver.connect("tcp://localhost:9000")
receiver.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
// Receiving image in bytes
image_bytes = receiver.recv()
int width = 4096; // My image width
int height = 4096; // My image height
// Converting bytes data to ndarray
image = numpy.frombuffer(image_byte, dtype=uint8).reshape((width, height))
```

**TO DO / IMPROVEMENT :** 
You can also pass the image size from the c++ publisher along with the image data.
So, that image can be reshaped accordingly at python side.

*ZMQ_SNDMORE flag comes handy here*

Just add another zmq_send statement at c++ side.

```
zmq_send(publisher, img_height, strlen(img_height), ZMQ_SNDMORE)
zmq_send(publisher, img_width, strlen(img_width), ZMQ_SNDMORE)
zmq_send(publisher, image.data, (height*width*sizeof(UINT8)), ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
```

Similarly, add corresponding receiving statements at python end.

```
height = receiver.recv_string(ZMQ_RCVMORE)
width = receiver.recv_string(ZMQ_RCVMORE)
image_bytes = receiver.recv()
```

---

**Another Improvement**

Thanks @Mark Setchell for pointing out an improvement.

Sending opencv Matrix of large size directly over network can be costly.
A better approach would be to encode the image before sending over the network.

***C++ Publisher :-***

```
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
int bind = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://*:9000");

// Reading the image through opencv package
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/sample.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
int height = image.rows;
int width = image.cols;
cv::vector<uchar> buffer;
cv::imencode(".jpg", image, buffer);
zmq_send(publisher, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
```

***Python Subscriber :-***

```
context = zmq.Context()
receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
receiver.connect("tcp://localhost:9000")
receiver.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
// Receiving image in bytes
image_bytes = receiver.recv()
// Decoding the image -- Python's PIL.Image library is used for decoding
image = numpy.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_byte)))
```

Comment: Sending a 16MB image uncompressed is potentially pretty wasteful of network bandwidth! Maybe consider using `cv2.imencode()` to convert to JPEG or PNG in memory before sending and it will likely be 200kB instead of 16MB.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks Mark for point out, I've updated the code with image encoding/decoding integrated at both c++ & python ends.

Comment: May you provide the inverse that is sending an image (encoded) from python client to c++ server?

Comment: An example of encoding before sending can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949615/9625777)