# What is the simplest, most productive approach to create prototype-grade Python bindings for existing C/C++ libraries?

Tags: python, binding, swig, ctypes

I want to create simple prototype-grade Python bindings to evaluate various C/C++ libraries.

I need to experiment on Linux, Windows and Mac.

Some examples of the libs that I need bindings for include a mix of C or C++ libraries such as things like:

- http://www.chokkan.org/software/cdbpp/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbh/
- http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3
- http://www.seg.rmit.edu.au/zettair/
- http://dbh.sourceforge.net/

There are several candidates out there, such as swig, ctypes, Boost.Python, pybindgen and questions were already posted here on the topic though the focus has been mostly on performance.  [Extending python - to swig, not to swig or Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456884/extending-python-to-swig-or-not-to-swig)

I care more about getting something simple and quickly than about performance.

What would you recommend to pick for creating bindings quickly?

Comment: I found some more things there: http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/wiki/RelatedProjects  and http://www.massey.ac.nz/massey/fms/Colleges/College%20of%20Sciences/IIMS/RLIMS/Volume13/Automatic_C_Library_Wrapping-Ctypes_from_the_Trenches.pdf : sounds like many of the writings on the wall point to ctypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) fits the bill pretty well for C. It's ridiculously easy to make thin wrappers around C libraries with it.

Comment: Would you know of a ctypes generator? aka some tool I could point to a c/c++ lib and would generate a wrapper for me?

Comment: @Philippe: Haven't seen one, though it does seem like the sort of thing that should exist.

Comment: I am still navigating the maze of options there... ctypes sounds like it is emerging as the std solution... I'll try to post a write-up when I am done

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Cython](http://cython.org/)?  It lets you bind to static libraries, and write your bindings in a language that looks like python.