# SWIG + SCIPY = Import Error on PyArray_TYPE

Tags: python, swig, scipy

Hey gang, so I've written a swig wrapper for some C code. I'm trying to bridge the gap between scipy arrays and C arrays, which I know is messy. After a clean compilation (well...not including some warnings...) I'm getting this issue when I load the python-swig-c module:

```
undefined symbol: PyArray_TYPE
```

I've added my swig interface file below - I've used the swig-pythonc tutorial to write this stuff:

```
%module pycimpl

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "cimpl.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%include "typemaps.i"

%apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1, int* INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM2, int* INPLACE_ARRAY3, int DIM3, double* INPLACE_ARRAY4, int DIM4, double* OUTPUT) { (double a[], int adim, int rowidx[], int rowidxdim, int colstr[], int colstrdim, double x[], int xdim, double* zeta) }

double cimpl(double a[], int adim, int ridx[], int ridxdim, int cstr[], int cstrdim, double x[], int xdim, double* zeta);

%include "cimpl.h"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

ct

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ctypes or pyrex/cython instead of SWIG?
(see [Python: SWIG vs ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135834/python-swig-vs-ctypes))

Comment: I've had some cross platform issues with ctypes in the past. At the time, I hadn't heard of cython and it was still in it's infancy. Pyrex seemed to be solving the same issue as SWIG (I'm just more familiar with SWIG), so I opted to stick with something I was already familiar working with, and SWIG has been around the block a lot longer.